# Custom sorting an array of strings in swift

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, swift2

Looking to sort an array `var myArray = ["Cat","Zoo","Ball","Cat"]` in an order such that all "Cat" (This can be anything) are @ front of the array and rest of the array is alphabetically sorted.

```
Input Array : ["Cat","Zoo","Ball","Cat"]
Expected Output Array: ["Cat", "Cat", "Ball", "Zoo"]
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is one of the solutions that I found:

```
var myArray = ["Cat","Zoo","Ball","Cat"]
let OrderString = "Cat"
myArray.sortInPlace({ (s1, s2) in
    //Sorting based on OrderString
    //First string is same as OrderString -- Don't swap order
    if s1 == OrderString{
        return true
    }else if s2 == OrderString { //Second String is same as OrderString -- Swap order
        return false
    }
    return s1.localizedStandardCompare(s2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
})

print(myArray)
```

[Demo Link](http://swiftstub.com/334576229/?v=beta)